# How do you handle native library conflicts in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

When I try to merge two branches that have different native libraries added to them (through `npm install X` and `react-native link`), I get conflicts in these files:

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in ios/myapp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in android/settings.gradle
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in android/app/src/main/java/com/myapp/MainApplication.java
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in android/app/build.gradle
```

What's the best way to resolve these conflicts? Should any of these files be gitignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gitignored. Absolutely NO. Go through each of the file and solve the merge if you like both native libraries to work.if not, you can choose between one the libraries by simply ignoring the other library changes. you can add your library or one you are pulling from has.
More here:
https://easyengine.io/tutorials/git/git-resolve-merge-conflicts/